# Check web site links

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, hyperlink

I have inherited a SQL Server 2008 database with 55000 organisation records in a table, each one with a web site address. Some of these web sites are not live and does anyone know how I can scan through the 55000 records and check if the web site addresses are valid rather than having to do this manually? Is there a tool available or any c# code. I am proficient in c# and asp.net MVC.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this but short of just writing the application for you I'm not exactly sure how I can help... what have you tried? What's the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want quick and dirty I suggest you use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write a C# console to do the following;

1. Access database
2. Query the organisation table and get URL
3. Use Webclient to test if page is 200
4. Record in Dictionary the success of each name

Comment: Thanks Owen, that's great, will give it a go.